# Using IF Function in Conditional Formatting to Change Value of User Input

Tags: excel

I need help with creating an IF function in conditional formatting.

Expected output:
IF E4 = 12, change E4 value to 1/1200

E4 is user input field so the formula needs to be created using conditional formatting or it needs to be entered in another cell besides E4.

[image: Excel snip]

Comment: Conditional formatting won't be able to update the same cell. Either you can use another cell or you have to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with VBA (You must call the Subroutine X).

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Const Row As Integer = 4
Private Const Column As Integer = 5
Private Const N As Long = 12

Sub X()
Dim F As Double
Dim S As String
Dim V As Variant

   V = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column)
   If (V = N) Then
      S = "1/1200"
      ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column) = S
   
      ' F = 1 / 1200
      ' S = F
      ' ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Column) = S
   End If
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!

I was able to find another vba code that worked for what I needed:

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4", "E43:E46")) Is Nothing Then
      If Target(1).value = "4" Then Target(1).value = "1/400"
      If Target(1).value = "5" Then Target(1).value = "1/500"
      If Target(1).value = "6" Then Target(1).value = "1/600"
      If Target(1).value = "7" Then Target(1).value = "1/700"
      If Target(1).value = "8" Then Target(1).value = "1/800"
      If Target(1).value = "9" Then Target(1).value = "1/900"
      If Target(1).value = "10" Then Target(1).value = "1/1000"
      If Target(1).value = "11" Then Target(1).value = "1/1100"
      If Target(1).value = "12" Then Target(1).value = "1/1200"
      If Target(1).value = "400" Then Target(1).value = "1/400"
      If Target(1).value = "500" Then Target(1).value = "1/500"
      If Target(1).value = "600" Then Target(1).value = "1/600"
      If Target(1).value = "700" Then Target(1).value = "1/700"
      If Target(1).value = "800" Then Target(1).value = "1/800"
      If Target(1).value = "900" Then Target(1).value = "1/900"
      If Target(1).value = "1000" Then Target(1).value = "1/1000"
      If Target(1).value = "1100" Then Target(1).value = "1/1100"
      If Target(1).value = "1200" Then Target(1).value = "1/1200"
   End If
End Sub
```